# Product of Absolutely Continuous Measures is Absolutely Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am stuck on this problem from Folland's *Real Analysis, Second Edition:*

*For $j = 1, 2$, let $\mu_j, \nu_j$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on $(X_j, \mathcal{M}_j)$ such that $\nu_j <\!\!< \mu_j$.  Then $\nu_1 \times \nu_2 <\!\!< \mu_1 \times \mu_2$.*

Here is about where I am at.

(1)  It is immediate that if $\mu_1 \times \mu_2(A \times B) = 0$, then $\nu_1 \times \nu_2(A \times B) = 0$.

(2)  Because $\nu_1 \times \nu_2$ is $\sigma$-finite, it is enough to prove the result for when $\nu_1 \times \nu_2$ is finite.  Since the result is quickly verified if either $\nu_1$ or $\nu_2$ is the zero measure, we may assume that both $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are finite.  We then have the following equivalent formulation for $\nu_1 <\!\!< \mu_1$:

*For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\mu_1(E) < \delta$ implies $\nu_1(E) < \epsilon$.*

And similarly for $\nu_2 <\!\!< \mu_2$.

I thought I might be able to prove the same condition for $\nu_1 \times \nu_2$ with respect to $\mu_1 \times \mu_2$, which would then imply $\nu_1 \times \nu_2 <\!\!< \mu_1 \times \mu_2$ since $\nu_1 \times \nu_2$ has been reduced to being finite.  As a suggestion, following Folland's technique, it might be easier to argue by contradiction, assuming first the $\epsilon-\delta$ condition is false.

(3)  If $\mu_1 \times \mu_2(E) = 0$, then, by definition,

$$0 = \inf \bigg\{ \sum_n \mu_1(A_n)\mu_2(B_n) \colon A_n \times B_n \text{ are rectangles such that } E \subset \bigcup_n A_n \times B_n\bigg\}.$$

To show $\nu_1 \times \nu_2(E) = 0$, we want to show that the analogous equation holds for $\nu_1 \times \nu_2$.

I can't seem to put the pieces together, despite some effort.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems this page may have the answers I need:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228928/radon-nikodym-derivative-of-product-measure?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that  $E\in M_1\times M_2$ such that $\mu_1\times \mu_2(E)=0$.

We have to show that $\nu_1\times \nu_2(E)=0.$

By Fubini's theorem, we have $$0=\mu_1\times \mu_2(E)=\int_{X_1}\mu_2(E \cap (\{x\} \times X_2))d\mu_1(x).$$ This means that
$$\color{blue}{\mu_1}(\{ x:\color{red}{\mu_2}(E\cap(\{x\}\times X_2))>0\})=0,$$ equivalently $$\color{blue}{\mu_1}(X_1\setminus\{x:\color{red}{\mu_2}(E\cap(\{x\}\times X_2))=0\})=0.$$
Since $\color{red}{\nu_2\ll\mu_2}$ we have $$\{x:\color{red}{\mu_2}(E\cap(\{x\}\times X_2))=0\}\subseteq\{x: \color{red}{\nu_2}(E\cap(\{x\}\times X_2))=0\}.$$ Since $\color{blue}{\nu_1\ll\mu_1}$ and $$\color{blue}{\mu_1}(X_1\setminus\{x:\color{red}{\nu_2}(E\cap(\{x\}\times X_2))=0\})=0,$$
we have
$$\color{blue}{\nu_1}(X_1\setminus\{x:\color{red}{\nu_2}(E\cap(\{x\}\times X_2))=0\})=\color{blue}{\nu_1}(\{x:\color{red}{\nu_2}(E\cap(\{x\}\times X_2))>0\})=0.$$ Finally, we get $$\begin{aligned}&\color{white}=\nu_1\times\nu_2(E)\\&=\int_{X_1}\nu_2(E\cap(\{x\}\times X_2))d\nu_1(x)\\&=\int_{\{ x : \nu_2(E \cap (\{x\}\times X_2))>0\} }\nu_2(E \cap (\{x\} \times X_2))d\nu_1(x)+
\int_{\{ x : \nu_2(E \cap (\{x\} \times X_2))=0\}}\nu_2(E \cap (\{x\} \times X_2))d\nu_1(x)\\&=0.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This question was stated at      http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040359/product-measures-and-absolute-continuity